# Create file - pipe to output

Tags: bash, pipe

At first I must say that my English is not very well.
I have to do my task from studies and I have a problem. I have to make file with version in the proper catalog. Information are in text file for example:

```
com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch;version=1.1.5
```

This is a direction to catalog, in which I have to create file:

```
1.1.5
```

Now I write:

```
egrep 'version=' bamboo.log | egrep --color -o '[^[:space:],\"](.+\.)+.+;version=[\"]*([[:digit:]]+\.)+[[:digit:]][\"]*' > tmp
cut -d ';' -f 1 tmp| tr '.' '/'| sed 's/$/\/version/'
```

I would do something like that:

```
cut -d ';' -f 1 tmp| tr '.' '/'| sed 's/$/\/version/'| echo $(cut -d '=' -f 2 < tmp) ) > -
```

Of course it doesn't work.

But I don't know how I can paste pipe (what is coming from pipe) as the name of file and simple version to 'echo'.

Could you help me with this problem?

Comment: Please make clear, possibly just by rewording, what your desired output is.

Answer (score 0):

You already have all the tools you need, except that `sed` will do everything `egrep` does without a separate call, so you are making the problem needlessly complex.

I don't know what else is in the file, but the following will isolate the version string in the example you have given:

```
sed<bamboo.log -n 's/^.*;version=//pg'
```

If you want to use the returned string as a file name, simply use the `$()` construct, as in:

```
FileName=$(sed<bamboo.log -n 's/^.*;version=//pg')
```

I have found a good reference/tutorial for `sed` [here](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html).